# How to print an array inside object that is coming from database?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript

I am trying to print an array "data" inside an object "clientData" but the problem is I cant access the array inside before it loads from the database, it gives me an error "Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'". How do I extract that array without specifying?

```
   this.adnService.getClient().subscribe((result) => {
      if (result === null) {
        this.empty = true;
      }
      this.clientData = result;
      console.log(this.clientData);
      console.log(this.clientData.data[0].client_id);
    })
```

Below is the clientData stringify output

```
{
  "status": "pass",
  "data": [
    {
      "client_id": "u616672",
      "client_name": "Client 123"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show what is `clientData` type and also what is the response received (in JSON)? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I have edited the question and added the output

Comment: How about if you specify as `any` type? `clientData: any;`

Comment: you can ensure the `data` exist or not using `this.clientData. hasOwnProperty('data')`

Comment: Another method you can try is checking with: `if (this.clientData && this.clientData.data) { /* Print */ }`.

Comment: It definitely has the property, but I cant use it directly in the code, the code doesnt understand what "data" is because its not offline but coming from database.

Comment: All these methods you are saying is correct but I cant use "data" in the code

Answer (score 0):

```
this.adnService.getClient().subscribe((result) => {
  if(result && result != ""){
    this.clientData = result;
    console.log(this.clientData);
    console.log(this.clientData.data[0].client_id);
  }else{
   this.empty = true;
  }
})

(or)
console.log(this.clientData?.data[0].client_id);
```